# Jqery delay не работает

Tags: jquery

Приветствую, знатоки.
Есть скрытая панелька, которая должна показываться по ховеру и убираться обратно когда ховера уже нет :)

вот код:

```
$('.btn-slide').hover(function(){
        $('.panel-wrapper').css("left", "0").delay(2000).css("left", "-192");
    });
```

И вот, собстно, проблема: по ховеру панелька показывается, а вот убираться ну никак не хочет.

Есть подозрения, что я туплю. Но вот где?
В общем, прошу помощи, знатоки.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/hover/ вы забыли написать еще одну функцию, второй  параметр `$( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неправильно его используете, почти все методы в jQuery синхронные, исключения show/hide/slide/fade/animate (и т.п.) В вашем случае нужно нужно использовать http://api.jquery.com/queue/

```
$('.btn-slide').hover(function(){
    $('.panel-wrapper').css("left", "0").delay(2000).queue(function (){
        $(this).css("left", "-192").deuque();
    });
});
```

Comment: Что-то не сработало, но все равно спасибо... сделал по совету выше :)

Comment: @fenris, не сработало потому, что значение "-192" не надо в кавычки брать, да "0" - тоже.

    $('.btn-slide').hover(function(){
        $('.panel-wrapper').css("left", 0).delay(2000).queue(function (){
            $(this).css("left", -192).deuque();
        });
    });